# ssh is too "powerful" for a remote git repository? how to setup permission?

Tags: git, permissions, ssh

I create a ssh server on my  suse box,basically I just want it to serve as a git server using ssh, but when I login with ssh  name@server   I can look at my home/repo directory, that's normal, but I can even check the file from other user such as home/steve which I don't want it to, How  to setup the user repo to only have access to git directory? say home/repo/repository.git ? or just files from /home/repo ?

I've disabled the "permit Root Login" from Yast2-sshd configuration tool (basically just a tool to edit /etc/sshd/sshd_config )",but it seems that's not enough.

Comment: I would suggest you to use gitolite (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). Then your users don't need to have a login in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh is too powerful in that it allows for an interactive session.
A [giZm0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481406/gizm0) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967461/ssh-is-too-powerful-for-a-remote-git-repository-how-to-setup-permission/11967640#comment15950449_11967461), [gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) is an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html) that can leverage the authentication provided by ssh and allows for a fine-grained level of access control over your repositories.
It is just a perl script, which can set itself in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in order to intercept any git command, and validate them against a simple text config file.
This takes advantage of an ssh feature (nothing to do with git), called [forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858).

Note: gitolite can also be linked with an httpd server: see "[Why do you need Gitosis or Gitolite?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10893091/6309)" or "[git on HTTP with gitolite and nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/377066/git-on-http-with-gitolite-and-nginx/377082#377082)" for more.

Comment: gitolite is easy to setup and flexible for permission issues.

Comment: @Drake agreed, and since gitolite V3 or 'g3' and its VREF, you can control *a lot* of things: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569263/git-hook-to-detect-file-changes-that-contain-a-certain-string/11573529#11573529 for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you [set the user's shell to be git-shell](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server), they can do nothing but run git commands.

If you don't need fine-grained permissions, then [you don't need gitolite or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888536/761202)